# How to capture console output in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, output, capture

I'm in the process of moving from JCreator to Eclipse.

When I hit build the button the output is shown at the bottm of the page, but I want my output to be shown in another window (typically black and white on JCreator).

Can anyone identify what the name of this window is and how to obtain this for eclipse?

I swear this answer should be on stack overflow, but I'm afraid my novice vocabulary is keeping me from finding the answer.

Comment: I'm guessing you may be used to using the command prompt/terminal. One way to use that is to build the project but not run it. Then use the terminal/command prompt and navigate to the file you want and run it from there.

Comment: You mean the console window?
Window->Show View->Console

Answer (score 1):

You can drag the console anywhere you want. If you move it outside the Eclipse window, it is completely detached.